# spring boot, проблема с websocket после деплоя в tomcat

Tags: spring, websocket, chat

Скачал пример чата на вебсокетах с [гитхаба](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat)
В STS все работает. После деплоя в tomcat сначала ничего не отображалось вообще, пока не унаследовал класс, где находится main от SpringBootServletInitializer и в build.gradle не прописал:

```
providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
```

Теперь можно успешно зайти на страницу авторизации, зайти в чат, но ничего написать нельзя и список пользователей пустой, а также пишет ошибку соединения. В чем может быть причина такого разного поведения ? STS насколько я понимаю тоже запускает через tomcat, но ошибок при этом не возникает. Подскажите пожалуйста как все-таки завести сокеты в приложении, которое работает на tomcat 8 ?

**Обновление**

Пробовал убирать библиотеки, которые нужны для работы с сокетами из своего приложения, поскольку читал, что tomcat использует свои, но приложение не запускалось, также указывал их как `providedRuntime`, но это не помогло.

**Обновление 2**

Нашел ошибку, в скриптах есть строчка `chatSocket.init("/ws");` Так вот, я проверил, оно соединяется не с chat/ws, а с /ws, наверное в этом и заключается ошибка, я правильно сделаю если напишу что-то вида `chatSocket.init(serverPrefix+"/ws");` или есть какая-то директива чтобы изменить корень? (неудобно, надо будет менять префикс для запуска через STS) Возможно я что-то путаю, недавно начал изучать скрипты и spring.

Comment: Разобрался в чем была проблема, надо было в  chatSocket.init();указывать путь "/chat/ws". Единственное что странно, при первой загрузке страницы с чатом ошибка соединения сокетов, а после перезагрузки все ок.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании spring tool suite страница с чатом находится по адресу localhost:8080/chat.html. Когда деплой происходит через tomcat корень сайта будет уже localhost:8080/<имя war файла>/. Поэтому в скриптах надо к адресу сокета "/ws" дописывать префикс <имя war файла>.